# Is there a tikz command for showing people in a flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, flow-charts

I need to show a group of people (sometimes women, sometimes men) in my flowchart. Is there any command for that?

Comment: There is [`tikzpeople`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople). Would that work? I'm sure you could construct groups of people from it.

Comment: http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpeople/tikzpeople.pdf

Comment: @DavidPurton You may also mention [tikzlings](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings?lang=en) for people like you and me. ;-)

Comment: @marmot, I did consider this ;)